# How to restore the state of checkboxes using WebExtensions storage API

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm building a firefox web extension and I'd like to give its users some options that they can check/uncheck. The state of the checkboxes is saved locally via the WebExtensions storage API, but I'm not quite sure how to restore the saved state for each option.

Here is the **options.html** file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
                <legend>My favorite veggies</legend>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="eggplant" id="eggplant" />Eggplant<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="zucchini" id="zucchini" />Zucchini<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="tomatoe" id="tomatoe" />Tomatoe<br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The **options.js** file that saves/restores the state of the checkboxes is as follows:

```js
function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

function saveOptions(e) {
  // List of search engines to be used
  let eggplant = {
      name: "Eggplant", 
      imageUrl: "https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Eggplant-1020x765.jpg",
      show: form.eggplant.checked
  };
  let zucchini = {
      name: "Zucchini", 
      imageUrl: "https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/zucchini.jpg",
      show: form.zucchini.checked
  };
  let tomatoe = {
      name: "Tomatoe", 
      imageUrl: "https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Organictomato1-1020x765.jpg",
      show: form.tomatoe.checked
  };
  let setting = browser.storage.sync.set({
    eggplant,
    zucchini,
    tomatoe
  });
  setting.then(null,onError);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function restoreOptions() {
  var gettingItem = browser.storage.sync.get({
    'show'
  });
  gettingItem.then((res) => {
    document.getElementById("eggplant").checked = eggplant.show;
    document.getElementById("zucchini").checked = zucchini.show;
    document.getElementById("tomatoe").checked = tomatoe.show;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreOptions);
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

Comment: Bad sign: your code has a syntax error, but it doesn't seem like you saw it. You should learn to debug webextension pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the state of your storage after the `set` operation:

```
{
  eggplant: {
    name: "Eggplant", 
    imageUrl: "https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Eggplant-1020x765.jpg",
    show: true
  },
  zucchini: { /* ... */ },
  tomatoe: { /* ... */ }
}
```

However, in `restoreOptions`, you query the storage with the key `"show"` - or, more specifically, with a syntactically incorrect object literal `{"show"}`.

Even if you fix it to be `"show"` is no such top-level key (and that's the only type of query you're allowed), so the result comes up as empty.

- If you want to query the entire storage, pass `null`.
- If you want to query a single top-level key, pass it as a string.
- If you want a set of top-level keys you know in advance, pass an array of key strings.
- If you want to provide a default in case the key is not in storage, pass an object mapping keys to defaults.

Here's how to organize your code with using defaults:

```
const defaults = {
  eggplant: {
    name: "Eggplant", 
    imageUrl: "(redacted for brevity)",
    show: false
  },
  zucchini: {
    name: "Zucchini", 
    imageUrl: "(redacted for brevity)",
    show: false
  },
  tomatoe: {
    name: "Tomatoe", 
    imageUrl: "(redacted for brevity)",
    show: false
  }
};

function saveOptions() {
  let settings = {}
  for (let setting in defaults) {
    settings[setting] = {
      ...defaults[setting],       // spread the default values
      show: form[setting].checked // override show with real data
    }
  } 
  browser.storage.sync.set(settings).then(null, onError);
}

function restoreOptions() {
  browser.storage.sync.get(defaults).then(
    (data) => {
      document.getElementById("eggplant").checked = data.eggplant.show;
      document.getElementById("zucchini").checked = data.zucchini.show;
      document.getElementById("tomatoe").checked = data.tomatoe.show;
    }
  );
}
```

Of note: don't use `submit` and `preventDefault`, just use `type="button"` inputs and `click`.

*Small edit:* Object spread (`...defaults[setting]`) is still experimental (though supported in recent Chrome/FF), a more [ES6-compliant code](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectPropertyAssignment) would be

```
for (let setting in defaults) {
  // shallow copy default settings
  settings[setting] = Object.assign({}, defaults[setting]);
  // override show property
  settings[setting].show = form[setting].checked;
}
```

Less concise, somewhat more compatible.

Comment: Hi Xan, thank you so much for answering so quickly. I only have difficulty understanding the two commented lines inside the for loop, especially "...defaults[setting]". I've never seen the "..." annotation before! Otherwise, I very much like the elegant way you created the defaults json object and fully understand the restoreOptions() function.

Comment: It's called "object spread" and is only supported in recent versions of Chrome (60+) and FF (55+). A safer, ES6-compliant version would be using `Object.assign()`

Comment: @OlivierdeBroqueville I've added alternative ES6-compliant code and hopefully it should be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Xan. Very kind of you. Always good to learn from experts!